# Arch linux; org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser”

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, d-bus, freedesktop, sway

I use sway on arch linux and a lot of apps log this error message:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser”
```

How can I resolve this issue ?
Thank you for help

PS: I use wayland + sway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` and adding this line to my sway config:

```
include /etc/sway/config.d/*
```